# How to filter results by multiple fields?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, filter, filtering, named-scope

I am working on a survey application in ruby on rails and on the results page I want to let users filter the answers by a bunch of demographic questions I asked at the start of the survey.

For example I asked users what their gender and career was.  So I was thinking of having dropdowns for gender and career.  Both dropdowns would default to all but if a user selected female and marketer then my results page would so only answers from female marketers.

I think the right way of doing this is to use named_scopes where I have a named_scope for every one of my demographic questions, in this example gender and career, which would take in a sanitized value from the dropdown to use at the conditional but i'm unsure on how to dynamically create the named_scope chain since I have like 5 demographic questions and presumably some of them are going to be set to all.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can chain named scopes together:

```
def index
  @results = Results.scoped
  @results = @results.gender(params[:gender]) unless params[:gender].blank?
  @results = @results.career(params[:career]) unless params[:career].blank?
end
```

I prefer however to use the [has_scope](http://github.com/plataformatec/has_scope) gem:

```
has_scope :gender
has_scope :career

def index
  @results = apply_scopes(Results).all
end
```

If you use [has_scope](http://github.com/plataformatec/has_scope) with [inherited_resources](http://github.com/josevalim/inherited_resources), you don't even need to define the index action.

Answer (score 3):

```
 named_scope :gender,lambda { |*args|
    unless args.first.blank?
      { :conditions => [ "gender = ?", args.first] }   
    end
  }
```

If you write named scopes in this way, you can have all them chained, and if one of your params will be blank wont breaks.

```
Result.gender("Male") will return male results.
Result.gender("") will return male and female too.
```

And you can chain all of your methods like this. Finally as a filtering you can have like:

```
Result.age(16).gender("male").career("beginer")
Result.age(nil).gender("").career("advanced") - will return results with advanced career, etc.
```

Answer (score 0):

Try some like this:

```
VistaFact.where( if active then {:field => :vista2} else {} end)
```

Or like this:

```
VistaFact.where(!data.blank? ? {:field=>data.strip} : {}).where(some? ? {:field2 => :data2} : {}).where ...
```

That work for me very nice!